# Google Calendar Event ID Created Can't Find Event Listed -- App Script/Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I have a script which has been running for almost 2 years.  I update the sheet with dates and either the event is deleted/created or a new one is created.

This last time I went through and added my dates its normal it populates the sheet cell with the event id and I am on my merry way -- however when I go to the calendar nothing shows up for that date/time.

Is there something I am missing like a new permission -- there are no errors thrown -- nothing in the logs.  I have an event id but I dont know how to check what is showing up as I cannot see it on the calendar -- Is there a way to check the event id and see what it contains.

The sheet (I separated with pipes)

Subject|Start Date|Start Time|End Date|End Time|All day event|Meeting Organizer|Description|Location|Reminder Date|Reminder Time|Show time as|Event ID|Status
Survey Edit: Science of HC Delivery|08/07/2017|12:00:00 AM|8/7/2017|12:00:00 PM|TRUE|Seamore Butz|||8/7/2017|9:00:00 AM|3   sg5a7jsakgbj8g5rejeos15lhc@google.com|y

```
function pushToCalendar() 
{
//spreadsheet variables
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 

/*
getRange (row,column,optNumRows,optNumColumns)  
row --- int --- top row of the range
column --- int--- leftmost column of the range
optNumRows --- int --- number of rows in the range.
optNumColumns --- int --- number of columns in the range
*/
var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow,13);
var values = range.getValues();   

//calendar variables
// xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com')
var numValues = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) 
{     
    //check to see if name and type are filled out - date is left off because length is "undefined"
    if (values[i][0].length > 0) 
    {
        //check if it's been entered before          
        if (values[i][13] == undefined) 
        {
            //create event https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_calendarapp#createEvent
            var newEventTitle = values[i][0];
          Logger.log(newEventTitle);
            var dateStart = values[i][1];
            var timeStart = values[i][2];
            var dateFinish = values[i][3];
            var timeFinish = values[i][4];

            var startDateTime = new Date(dateStart+" "+timeStart);
            startDateTime.setDate(startDateTime.getDate());
            startDateTime.setMonth(startDateTime.getMonth());
            startDateTime.setYear(startDateTime.getYear());
            startDateTime.setTime(startDateTime.getTime());

            var stopDateTime = new Date(dateFinish+" "+timeFinish);
            stopDateTime.setDate(stopDateTime.getDate());
            stopDateTime.setMonth(stopDateTime.getMonth());
            stopDateTime.setYear(stopDateTime.getYear());
            stopDateTime.setTime(stopDateTime.getTime());

            var description = (values[i][7] == '' ? 'Test Description '+i : values[i][7]);
            var location = (values[i][8] == '' ? 'Test Location '+i : values[i][8]);

          Logger.log(description);
          Logger.log(location);

            //var newEvent = calendar.createAllDayEvent(newEventTitle, values[i][1]);
            var newEvent = calendar.createEvent(newEventTitle, startDateTime, stopDateTime, {description:description,location:location});

            //get ID
            var newEventId = newEvent.getId();

            //mark as entered, enter ID
            sheet.getRange(i+2,14).setValue('y');
            sheet.getRange(i+2,13).setValue(newEventId);

            // in case of larger sheets we need to sleep the process
            Utilities.sleep(1000);

        } 
        else if (values[i][14] == 'u') 
        {
            // can update event so need to delete and create again
            // delete event
            var event = calendar.getEventSeriesById(values[i][9]);
            event.deleteEventSeries();

            //create event 
            var newEventTitle = values[i][0];

            //create event https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_calendarapp#createEvent
            var newEventTitle = values[i][0];
            var dateStart = values[i][1];
            var timeStart = values[i][2];
            var dateFinish = values[i][3];
            var timeFinish = values[i][4];

            var startDateTime = new Date(dateStart+" "+timeStart);
            startDateTime.setDate(startDateTime.getDate());
            startDateTime.setMonth(startDateTime.getMonth());
            startDateTime.setYear(startDateTime.getYear());
            startDateTime.setTime(startDateTime.getTime());

            var stopDateTime = new Date(dateFinish+" "+timeFinish);
            stopDateTime.setDate(stopDateTime.getDate());
            stopDateTime.setMonth(stopDateTime.getMonth());
            stopDateTime.setYear(stopDateTime.getYear());
            stopDateTime.setTime(stopDateTime.getTime());

            var description = (values[i][7] == undefined ? 'Test Description '+i : values[i][7]);
            var location = (values[i][8] == undefined ? 'Test Location '+i : values[i][8]);

            //var newEvent = calendar.createAllDayEvent(newEventTitle, values[i][1]);
            var newEvent = calendar.createEvent(newEventTitle, startDateTime, stopDateTime, {description:description,location:location});

            //get ID
            var newEventId = newEvent.getId();

            //mark as entered, enter ID
            sheet.getRange(i+2,14).setValue('y');
            sheet.getRange(i+2,13).setValue(newEventId);

            // in case of larger sheets we need to sleep the process
            Utilities.sleep(1000);

        } 
        else 
        {
           Logger.log('I am groot');
           sheet.getRange(i+2,14).setValue('y');
        }
    }

    numValues++;
}

}

function onOpen() 
{
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var menuEntries = [];  
    menuEntries.push({name: "Grades & Evals", functionName:         "pushToCalendar"}); 
    sheet.addMenu("Sync to Academic Master", menuEntries);  
}
```

Comment: At the very least show us the lines of code that create/delete the event.  And give us a sample of the input values.  It's possible that the problem is not with the code.  The format of the date may be different.  The date might be wrong.  An event might have been created, but created in the year 1899, or something like that.

Comment: Sorry about that I am kinda new to Stack so was having trouble with adding code.  Here are the goods.

Comment: There are `Logger.log()` statements in your code.  So, I'm assuming that you know how to use `Logger.log()`.  The line of code that gets the start date is: `var dateStart = values[i][1];`  and then there are 3 lines under that.  Add some `Logger.log()` statements to determine exactly what the value is.  We don't know what the values of the variables are.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue finally .. one of those tiny issue found after logging more and googling the Invalid Date response.

On line 16 this

```
var values = range.getValues();
```

needed to change to this

```
var values = range.getDisplayValues();
```

So thanks :)